# How do i extract the date from filename through sql

Tags: sql, substring

My file name is like below

```
dbfs:/mnt/edpraw/raw_daily_flash/raw_daily_flash_eu/partition_ts=20221010151556/eu_dsf_20221010050123_2022101004.csv
```

I want to get the output like `20221010050123`

Comment: I think the way to do it depends on the DBMS that you are using. Are you using [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)? Also, are you asking specifically for the string in your question or is that just an example?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? All answers are product specific, for different dbms:es...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what SQL you are using but many do support split_part so your query would look like this:

```
SELECT split_part(split_part('dbfs:/mnt/edpraw/raw_daily_flash/raw_daily_flash_eu/partition_ts=20221010151556/eu_dsf_20221010050123_2022101004.csv', '/',7), '_', 3);
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it dynamically without passing indexes:

```
    declare @path nvarchar(MAX) = 'dbfs:/mnt/edpraw/raw_daily_flash/raw_daily_flash_eu/partition_ts=20221010151556/eu_dsf_20221010050123_2022101004.csv'
    declare @time nvarchar(MAX)
    
    --first extract before last '_'
    set @time = left(@path, len(@path) - charindex('_', reverse(@path) + '_'))
    print @time

    --then extract after last '_'
    set @time = right(@time, charindex('_', reverse(@time) + '_') - 1)
    print @time
```

**Note**
this will work no matter change in length of path, but format.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: this query is for SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

max(substr(source_file_name FROM -29 for 14)) as latest_file_ts,